# Configure the org.jooq.conf.Settings.backslashEscaping property

Tags: jooq

In the book "Beginning jOOQ" by Tayo Koleoso it is written:

```
Caution For your own peace of mind, go ahead and configure the
org.jooq.conf.Settings.backslashEscaping property on
your Settings object. MySQL and some versions of PostgreSQL
support non-standard escape characters that can cause you a lot of
grief when you least expect it. This property lets jOOQ properly handle
this “feature” from MySQL.
```

The problem is that to the best of my ability I can't find in the book how toconfigure this.

**Pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>jooq</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>jooq</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jooq</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306/testdb
spring.datasource.username=testdb
spring.datasource.password=testdb
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/start")
public class StartController {
    @GetMapping("/")
    public void start() {

        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.
                getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?user=testdb&password=testdb")) {
            DSLContext context = DSL.using(connection, SQLDialect.MYSQL);


            ResultQuery resultQuery = context.
                        resultQuery("SELECT * FROM edens_car.complete_car_listing");
            List<CompleteVehicleRecord> allVehicles =
            resultQuery.fetchInto(CompleteVehicleRecord.class);

        } catch (SQLException sqlex) {
            assert true;
        }
    }
}
```

I just organised the Spring Controller for my convenience, don't pay attention to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Adapting your example code

You can pass custom `Settings` to one of the [`DSL.using()` overloads](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#using(java.sql.Connection,org.jooq.SQLDialect,org.jooq.conf.Settings)), specifically:

```java
DSLContext context = DSL.using(connection, SQLDialect.MYSQL, settings);
```

Noting that these methods are just convenience for creating your own [`DefaultConfiguration`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DefaultConfiguration.html)

### A Spring Boot `DefaultConfigurationCustomizer`

Alternatively, [if you're using Spring Boot, then this article shows how to use a `DefaultConfigurationCustomizer`](https://blog.jooq.org/how-to-customise-a-jooq-configuration-that-is-injected-using-spring-boot/), e.g.:

```java
@Bean
public DefaultConfigurationCustomizer configurationCustomiser() {
    return (DefaultConfiguration c) -> c.settings()
        .withBackslashEscaping(...);
}
```